# Explicit wait is not working if the element located is of 'text'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

Explicit wait is not working if the element located is of 'text'. But it is working fine if the driver performs some action i.e, entering text into text box or clicking a webelement etc.

```
public boolean waitForPageToLoad(String timeOutInSeconds) throws ScreenShotException, InterruptedException {
    boolean bFlag = false;
    WebElement element;
    boolean bStatus = true;
    int timeinseconds1 = Integer.parseInt(timeOutInSeconds);

    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeinseconds1);
        while(timeinseconds1 > 0) {
            element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
            Log.info("Element status at runtime -->"+element.isDisplayed());
            if(!element.isDisplayed()) {
                timeinseconds1 = timeinseconds1 - 500;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("working");
                bFlag = bStatus;
                Log.info("Element status: - >"+bFlag);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        screenShot.screenShot(e);
    }

    return bFlag;
}
```

The above code doesnt work if my locator is of text i.e, say if I want to check whether 'Title' of the question in the stackoverflow is visible or not within 40seconds.Driver will wait for 40seconds though the title appears less than that.  But, it works fine if the locator is Title text box. Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: please provide ur html portion for type text.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do there?  That code makes no sense!  You have managed to stick an explicit wait into a while loop with a Thread.sleep() whilst changing variable types and generally doing a bunch of batshit crazy stuff.  You have taken the definition of doing it wrong and pushed it to a totally new level...

Comment: lolll..why didnt you post the correct code if you know it?

Comment: Because it is unclear what you are trying to do and you have not provided any markup that you are working with.  I could try vomiting out various bits of code that may help, but until I know what your real problem is and what you are trying to do it would be worthless.  One example is that you seem to be using a static locator even though this looks like it's trying to be a generic method.  Your question needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wait quite differently that it is supposed to be used.

```
try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeinseconds1);
    element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
} catch (TimeOutException toe) {
  //handle the page not loading
}
//from now on continue the code as synchronous knowing that the page is loaded
```

Comment: I admit my comment was a little harsh, it was hard to come up with a sensible answer like this while suffering the pain of my eyes bleeding out.

Comment: Thank you aris for providing the solution.However, the result is same i.e, Driver waits till 40 secs even the locator(text) appears less than that time.

Comment: trying the solution, if it waits for the full time and you get a timeoutexception then the code with the visibility needs to change. sometimes you need to target the container div. In any case this is the correct approach to the code you only need to tweek how to target the element.